"ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined" while using Jest in Next.js 14
I am trying to run some tests for some of. the methods that are used to make a call to an API. I am using Jest on Next.js 14.
My jest.config.js is:
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: "./",
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const config = {
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/components/$1",
    "^@/lib/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/lib/$1",
  },
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(config);

And my jestconfig.json is:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}

I created a "test" folder in the root of the project and inside of it, I created the test:
import { getRanking, createRanking, updateRanking } from "@/lib/apiCalls";

describe("getRanking function", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchMock.mockClear();
  });

  it("fetches data successfully", async () => {
    const mockData = [{ id: 1, name: "Player A", score: 100 }];
    fetchMock.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      json: async () => mockData,
    });

    const result = await getRanking();
    expect(result).toEqual(mockData[0]);
    expect(fetchMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(fetchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RANKING_API_URL,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
  });

  it("handles errors", async () => {
    fetchMock.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error("API is down"));

    const result = await getRanking();
    expect(result).toBeUndefined();
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Error("API is down"));
  });
});

describe("createRanking function", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchMock.mockClear();
  });

  it("creates ranking successfully", async () => {
    fetchMock.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      json: async () => ({ success: true }),
    });

    await createRanking();
    expect(fetchMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(fetchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RANKING_API_URL,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
  });

  it("handles errors", async () => {
    fetchMock.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error("Failed to create ranking"));

    await createRanking();
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      new Error("Failed to create ranking")
    );
  });
});

describe("updateRanking function", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchMock.mockClear();
  });

  it("updates ranking successfully", async () => {
    const mockWinner = "Player B";
    const mockRanking = [{ id: 1, name: "Player A", score: 100 }];

    fetchMock.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      json: async () => ({ success: true }),
    });

    await updateRanking(mockWinner, mockRanking);
    expect(fetchMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(fetchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RANKING_API_URL,
      {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          winner: mockWinner,
          ranking: mockRanking,
        }),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
  });

  it("handles errors", async () => {
    const mockWinner = "Player B";
    const mockRanking = [{ id: 1, name: "Player A", score: 100 }];

    fetchMock.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error("Failed to update ranking"));

    await updateRanking(mockWinner, mockRanking);
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      new Error("Failed to update ranking")
    );
  });
});

The file, apiCalls.js, that I want to test contains three methods:
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const getRanking = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RANKING_API_URL, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    if (data) return data[0];
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const createRanking = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RANKING_API_URL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const data = await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const updateRanking = async (winner, ranking) => {
  const args = {
    winner: winner,
    ranking: ranking,
  };
  try {
    const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RANKING_API_URL, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(args),
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const data = await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

When I run the test, it just shows me the following error:
ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

      20 |   try {
      21 |     const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RANKING_API_URL, {
    > 22 |       method: "POST",
         |                                                    ^
      23 |       headers: {
      24 |         "content-type": "application/json",
      25 |       },

I have never used Jest and I do not know what is happening...
I tried to changed the values of jest.config.js and jestconfig.json files, but the error persists
Thanks in advance for the help!

I've faced this issue before, though not with Next.js particularly. In any case, it seems you're facing an issue that has been already reported here. You could probably fix this by adding a polyfill for TextEncoder and add it to test environment setup.

Install text-encoding as a dev devependency.

npm install --save-dev text-encoding


Create a file somewhere in your project named setupEnv.js with the following content:

TextDecoder = require('text-encoding').TextDecoder;


Add setupEnv.js to the setupFiles configuration in your jest.config.js:

const config = {
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/components/$1",
    "^@/lib/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/lib/$1",
  },
  setupFiles: ['path/to/setupEnv.js'],
};

